# Stuck threads exception

Tags: nullpointerexception

I am deploying a JSF application on oracle weblogic server. The server is crashing down on load and I started performance Testing with J-meter and it gives me feed as to which page is failing to load. I started debugging with a single user nad got the following feed from admin log:

Adminserver.log

```
####<Dec 7, 2012 2:53:34 PM GMT+05:30> <Error> <HTTP> <CDCUBPEDB> <AdminServer> <[STUCK] 

ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> 

<> <> <1354872214767> <BEA-101107> <[ServletContext@6958453[app:dummyapp module:/app 

path:/app spec-version:1.0]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: parent is null?
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.findComponent(UIComponentTag.java:545)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.doStartTag(UIComponentTag.java:315)
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag.doStartTag(ViewTag.java:73)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__errordisplay._jspService(__errordisplay.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper

.java:227)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java

:523)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at 

org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalCo

ntextImpl.java:419)
    at 

org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesVie

wHandlerImpl.java:236)
    at 

org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesV

iewHandlerImpl.java:222)
    at 

org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:

41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper

.java:227)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java

:523)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:720)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:591)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:150)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServl

etContext.java:2348)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2190)
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
>
```

when load increases it shows up on console "your session has been expired" in the beginning itself. With one or two users sometimes it is fine but still some times shows :connection time out" on the browser and on console it says:

```
Problem occurred while serving the error page.
javax.servlet.ServletException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2348)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2190)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:43)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2348)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2190)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused By: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkNoTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:591)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:540)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:427)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.flush(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:188)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.endDocument(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag.doEndTag(ViewTag.java:103)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__errordisplay._jspService(__errordisplay.java:149)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2348)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2190)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
>
```